Ansible: How if fact exists do x else do y?
I am using Ansible to create a hosts file for each of my servers, based on gathered facts, I am including the default IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and all works fine.
What I am struggling to work out is how to populate the template when there is no IPv6 address?
I am using
{{ ansible_default_ipv6.address }}   {{ inventory_hostname }}  {{ inventory_hostname_short }}

but if none exists the task fails.
I'm not sure what to try.

Q: "How to populate the template when there is no IPv6 address?"
In example with Jinja2 Template Tests.
The template file could look like hosts.j2
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ inventory_hostname_short }}
{% if ansible_default_ipv6.address is defined %}
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
{{ ansible_default_ipv6.address }} {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ inventory_hostname_short }}
{% endif %}

the task just
- name: Template a file to /etc/hosts
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: templates/hosts.j2
    dest: /etc/hosts

and adapt, adjust, enhance to your needs.
Similar Q&A and Documentation

In Jinja2, How do you test if a variable is undefined?
Conditionals based on variables


You can use the filter default. For example,
{{ ansible_default_ipv6.address | default('none') }}



Example of a complete playbook for testing
shell> cat pb.yml 

- hosts: test_01,test_02,test_03

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset:
          - all_ipv4_addresses
          - all_ipv6_addresses

    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}
          ansible_all_ipv6_addresses: {{ ansible_all_ipv6_addresses }}
          ansible_default_ipv4: {{ ansible_default_ipv4 }}
          ansible_default_ipv6: {{ ansible_default_ipv6 }}

    - debug:
        msg: |
          default IPv6: {{ ansible_default_ipv6.address | default('none') }}

gives
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [test_01,test_02,test_03] **************************************************************************************

TASK [setup] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01]
ok: [test_03]
ok: [test_02]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: ['10.1.0.51']
    ansible_all_ipv6_addresses: []
    ansible_default_ipv4: {}
    ansible_default_ipv6: {}
ok: [test_02] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: ['10.1.0.52']
    ansible_all_ipv6_addresses: []
    ansible_default_ipv4: {}
    ansible_default_ipv6: {}
ok: [test_03] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: ['10.1.0.53']
    ansible_all_ipv6_addresses: []
    ansible_default_ipv4: {}
    ansible_default_ipv6: {}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: |-
    default IPv6: none
ok: [test_02] => 
  msg: |-
    default IPv6: none
ok: [test_03] => 
  msg: |-
    default IPv6: none

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_02                    : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_03                    : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0


